# Re-arranging HTML Page

Tags: html, css

As you can see from my code the 4 sections are piled up. It would be great if someone could please help me spread them evenly across the page. The 4 sections that are: The History Of Gaming, Atari, Other Games, Future gaming.

```css
.jumbotron h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 150px;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url('http://i118.photobucket.com/albums/o117/Shawnthebro/bandicam2014-03-2311-20-03-210_zpse7f7712f.jpg');
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 100px;
  height: 350px;
  display: block;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ff0000;
  font-size: 50px;
  bottom: 350px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
}
.page ul {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  padding-left: 75px;
  .page ul li {
    display: inline;
  }
  .page a {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    padding-left: 70px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
  <title>Gaming T,N & B</title>
</head>

<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Gaming: Then, Now & Beyond</h1>
  </div>
</div>


<body>


  <div class="nav">
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/hog.html">History of Gaming</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/atari.html">Atari</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/othergames.html">Other Games</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/future.html">Future</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


  <style>
    div.img {
      margin: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      float: left;
      width: 180px;
    }
    div.img:hover {
      border: 1px solid #777;
    }
    div.img img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    div.desc {
      padding: 15px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="img">
      <a target="_blank" href="history.png">
        <img src="history.png" alt="The History of Gaming" width="300" height="200">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">
        <div class="page">
          <div class="container">
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <h3>History of Gaming</h3>
                  <ul>
                    <li>What is gaming?</li>
                    <li>Pong</li>
                    <li>Technology Boom</li>
                  </ul>
                  <p><a href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/hog.html">Learn more about the history of gaming</a>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="img">
              <a target="_blank" href="atari.jpg">
                <img src="atari.jpg" alt="Atari" width="600" height="400">
              </a>
              <div class="desc">
                <div>
                  <h3>Atari</h3>
                  <ul>
                    <li>40 years of fun</li>
                    <li>Who is Nolan Bushnell</li>
                    <li>Bought & Sold</li>
                  </ul>
                  <p><a href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/atari.html">Learn more about Atari</a>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="img">
              <a target="_blank" href="xbox_ps1.jpg">
                <img src="xbox_ps1.jpg" alt="Other Games" width="600" height="400">
              </a>
              <div class="desc">
                <div>
                  <h3>Other Games</h3>
                  <ul>
                    <li>PC</li>
                    <li>Xbox</li>
                    <li>PlayStation</li>
                  </ul>
                  <p><a href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/othergames.html">Learn more about other games</a>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="img">
              <a target="_blank" href="future_ocu.jpg">
                <img src="future_ocu.jpg" alt="Future Gaming" width="600" height="400">
              </a>
              <div class="desc">
                <div>
                  <h3>Future</h3>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Gaming in society</li>
                    <li>Who is driving who?</li>
                    <li>CrowdFunding</li>
                  </ul>
                  <p><a href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/future.html">Learn about future gaming</a>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <iframe width="1150" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/X1tBEKFYKJg?autoplay=1" style="border:5px dotted red">
      </iframe>


  </body>

</html>
```

Many Thanks

Adam

Comment: I couldn't find where you declared the container style.  I'd say create it, and give it a sufficient height. ...and if that doesn't work, make a jsfiddle -- easier for us to edit and manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code structure is not valid. I just revised it. The `head` tag was opened twice and the `style` was placed inside the body. The `body` tag was also opened multiple times and some `div` tags were not closed.

```css
.jumbotron h1 {
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 150px;
font-family: Sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 0px;
}
.jumbotron {
background-image: url('http://i118.photobucket.com/albums/o117/Shawnthebro/bandicam2014-03-2311-20-03-210_zpse7f7712f.jpg');
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 100px;
height: 350px;
display: block;
}
.nav li {
display: inline;
text-align: center;
color: #ff0000;
font-size: 50px;
bottom: 350px;
padding-left: 35px;
font-family: Sans-serif;
}
.page ul {
color: #000000;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: Calibri;
padding-left: 75px;
.page ul li {
display: inline;
}
.page a {
color: #000000;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: Calibri;
padding-left: 70px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
      <title>Gaming T,N & B</title>
      <style>
         div.img {
         margin: 5px;
         border: 1px solid #ccc;
         float: left;
         width: 180px;
         }
         div.img:hover {
         border: 1px solid #777;
         }
         div.img img {
         width: 100%;
         height: auto;
         }
         div.desc {
         padding: 15px;
         text-align: center;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="jumbotron">
         <div class="container">
            <h1>Gaming: Then, Now & Beyond</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="nav">
         <div class="container">
            <ul>
               <li><a href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/hog.html">History of Gaming</a>
               </li>
               <li><a href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/atari.html">Atari</a>
               </li>
               <li><a href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/othergames.html">Other Games</a>
               </li>
               <li><a href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/future.html">Future</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="img">
         <a target="_blank" href="history.png">
         <img src="history.png" alt="The History of Gaming" width="300" height="200">
         </a>
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
         <div class="page">
            <div class="container">
               <div>
                  <div>
                     <div>
                        <h3>History of Gaming</h3>
                        <ul>
                           <li>What is gaming?</li>
                           <li>Pong</li>
                           <li>Technology Boom</li>
                        </ul>
                        <p><a href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/hog.html">Learn more about the history of gaming</a>
                        </p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="img">
                  <a target="_blank" href="atari.jpg">
                  <img src="atari.jpg" alt="Atari" width="600" height="400">
                  </a>
                  <div class="desc">
                     <div>
                        <h3>Atari</h3>
                        <ul>
                           <li>40 years of fun</li>
                           <li>Who is Nolan Bushnell</li>
                           <li>Bought & Sold</li>
                        </ul>
                        <p><a href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/atari.html">Learn more about Atari</a>
                        </p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="img">
                  <a target="_blank" href="xbox_ps1.jpg">
                  <img src="xbox_ps1.jpg" alt="Other Games" width="600" height="400">
                  </a>
                  <div class="desc">
                     <div>
                        <h3>Other Games</h3>
                        <ul>
                           <li>PC</li>
                           <li>Xbox</li>
                           <li>PlayStation</li>
                        </ul>
                        <p><a href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/othergames.html">Learn more about other games</a>
                        </p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="img">
                  <a target="_blank" href="future_ocu.jpg">
                  <img src="future_ocu.jpg" alt="Future Gaming" width="600" height="400">
                  </a>
                  <div class="desc">
                     <div>
                        <h3>Future</h3>
                        <ul>
                           <li>Gaming in society</li>
                           <li>Who is driving who?</li>
                           <li>CrowdFunding</li>
                        </ul>
                        <p><a href="file:///Users/AdamMahmoud/Documents/School/Year%2010/IT/website_name/future.html">Learn about future gaming</a>
                        </p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <iframe width="1150" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/X1tBEKFYKJg?autoplay=1" style="border:5px dotted red">
      </iframe>
   </body>
</html>
```

The CSS code was not working because of invalid structure, now try layout your document and it should work now.

Comment: my mistake, when i said the 4 parts I mean the ones inbetween the youtube video and the image! not the nav bar! @maihannijat

Comment: @JamesM Please provide more information. It's still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

James's answer would probably still work if you apply the same technique to that section. Since that is technically his answer, I will offer an alternative solution. You could add this to your CSS:

```
ul {text-align-justify}
```

Or if you only want that rule to apply to that section, you can give that UL an ID and apply it to the ID in the CSS.

I would also recommend moving the h1 section down into the body.